# jboss-web.xml validation error

Tags: java, xml, validation, web-applications, jboss

Why do i have a validation error on the element "resource-ref" in this very simple jboss-web.xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd"
    version="6.0">

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/RoadsDB</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/RoadsDB</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>

</jboss-web>
```

If i put the xml declarations away like this, i have no problem deploying my app:

```
<jboss-web>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/RoadsDB</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:/RoadsDB</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>

</jboss-web>
```

I would just like to know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you going to say what the error was, or leave us guessing?

Comment: It is a validation error on "resource-ref"-element.

Comment: Eclipse gives me the error message: Invalid content was found starting with element "resource-ref".
And JBoss says: Failed to resolve Java binding for .../jboss-web.xml (check the schema binding resolver configuration)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be because JBoss does not like to parse the schema definitions if you put them in your jboss-web.xml file, even though it is perfectly valid XML. So if you want to add the definitions so tools like the Eclipse XML editor can use them, you're out of luck unless you remove them again before deploying your app.

Maybe somebody from the JBoss AS team can comment.

FWIW, here's the error you get on JBoss 6.0 Final if you include the schema definitions.

```
12:47:27,359 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///C:/Development/SGMS/ChinaMobile/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1305317047609/deploy/ChinaTDS.ear state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///C:/Development/SGMS/ChinaMobile/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1305317047609/deploy/ChinaTDS.ear/ChinaTDS_Web.war/
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployment.JBossWebAppParsingDeployer.createMetaData(JBossWebAppParsingDeployer.java:99) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployment.JBossWebAppParsingDeployer.createMetaData(JBossWebAppParsingDeployer.java:80) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.0.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.Exception: Failed to resolve Java binding for /C:/Development/SGMS/ChinaMobile/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1305317047609/deploy/ChinaTDS.ear/ChinaTDS_Web.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml (check the SchemaBinding resolver configuration)
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:259) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:352) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:334) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:251) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:369) [:2.2.0.GA]
... 76 more
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `resource-ref` doesn't exists with schema jboss-web_6_0.xsd. These are the following elements **valid** for jboss-web_6_0.xsd.

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="class-loading" type="jboss:class-loadingType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="security-domain" type="jboss:security-domainType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="jacc-star-role-allow" type="jboss:jacc-star-role-allowType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="context-root" type="jboss:context-rootType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="virtual-host" type="jboss:virtual-hostType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="use-session-cookies" type="jboss:use-session-cookiesType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="replication-config" type="jboss:replication-configType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:group ref="jboss:jndiEnvironmentRefsGroup"/>
    <xsd:element name="security-role" type="jboss:security-roleType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="message-destination" type="jboss:message-destinationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="webservice-description" type="jboss:webservice-descriptionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="depends" type="jboss:dependsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="servlet" type="jboss:servletType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="max-active-sessions" type="jboss:max-active-sessionsType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="passivation-config" type="jboss:passivation-configType" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="annotation" type="jboss:annotationType" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Comment: Yes. I know this, because eclipse gives me autocompletion for these elements. But this does not solve the problem. Because resource-ref seems to be allowed here, because jboss evaluates this entry to setup my datasource binding. Or how else should i describe my resource references?

Comment: Resource reference is described in `web.xml`. The jboss way (if I'm not mistaken) was acceptable in jboss 3 and 4. After that, I never worked with JBoss so I can't really help.

Comment: Thank you very much. What really confuses me about this problem is, that jboss on one hand needs this entry, but on the other hand the schema does not allow it.

Comment: I think they're doing this for backward compatibility

Comment: Wrong answer. jboss-web_6_0.xsd contains the clause '<xsd:include schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-common_6_0.xsd"/>' and [http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbosscommon/jboss-common_6_0.xsd](http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbosscommon/jboss-common_6_0.xsd) contains the definition of the `resource-ref` element. Right answer: make sure the resolver can access `jboss-common_6_0.xsd` included XSD.

Comment: If you check your post, you are referring to `jboss-common_6_0.xsd` and **not** `jboss-web_6_0.xsd`. As I said earlier, the `jboss-web` element has no `<xsd:sequence>` element referring to `resource-ref`. Thanks for the downvote.