# jboss-web.xml validation error in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jboss

This is the content of my jboss file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>value</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>value</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>value</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>value</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>value</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>value</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>validate</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</jboss-web>
```

I am receiving following error in eclipse

```
The content of element type "jboss-web" must match "(class-loading?,security-domain?,context-root?,virtual-host*,use-session-cookies?,replication-config?,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-role*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*,message-destination-ref*,message-destination*,webservice-description*,service-ref*,depends*,servlet*,authenticators*)".
jboss-web.xml   line 4  XML Problem
```

Please help.

Comment: What are the "other elements" ? That's probably where the error is. Eclipse is validating the xml file against the DTD referenced in the url above. The error message is saying that one of the direct children of `<jboss-web>` is none of those listed in the message

Comment: thank you for your response I have update the question.please let me know if anything else is required

Comment: R u using `JBoss 4` ? u have added `jboss-web_4_0.dtd` in ur `DOCTYPE`. Is ur JBoss AS or EAP ?

Comment: Have a look at this [jboss-web.xml validation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605096/jboss-web-xml-validation-error)

Comment: @OO7 yeah we are still using jboss 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `<servlet-mapping>` does not belong there, as it is not part of the allowed children for `<jboss-web>`, as declared in the DTD.

As far as I know, `<servlet-mapping>` should be in the web.xml instead.

Comment: even though I have moved the servlet-mapping to web.xml I can still see those error.

Answer (score 1):

Lolo is correct, the `<servlet-mapping/>` tag should be in the the `web.xml` instead.
The `web.xml` descriptor defines the web application independent of the deployment environment, while the jboss-web.xml descriptor is meant to map those configuration elements to its actual deployed environment.
That is why it contains those `<resource-ref/>` elements to map a resource defined in the `web.xml` to a particular jndi name for instance.

Besides moving the `<servlet-mapping/>` element you should also move the `<servlet/>` element to the `web.xml`.

In case you still have issues you could have eclipse validate the web.xml for you. If configured properly you can even use auto-complete while editing the xml files, see http://eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/XMLValidation/XMLValidationTutorial.html.